# Mouse Wheel Scroll in question body is not bound

Tags: bug, status-declined, design

I noticed today that it is now possible to scroll the body of a question (but not on the main page) with the middle-click scrolling mousewheell.

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is using Chrome 14.0.835.186 m, on windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: I remember something to that effect, but can't repro in Chrome 16

Comment: Weird. I can't reproduce this bug on my PC -- just my laptop.

Comment: @Jeff - erm. Wouldn't "status-norepro" make more sense than "status-declined"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [bug with Chrome](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=89366).  Itt has been fixed in their development channel, and will make its way into stable eventually.

For more, see the [original post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106451/140548) on MSO

Comment: Weird. My PC *says* its running the same version of Chrome (14), but it doesn't have this bug.